# Destroying Phaser.Image object through Button click results in TypeError

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am making a HTML5 game using Phaser-framework (version 2.2.2) and JavaScript. I am now creating some UI elements for the game. The following code is representing a UI window in the game.

```
var PointEditScreen = function(game) {
  Phaser.Image.call(this, game, 600, 50, 'background');
  var exitButton = game.add.button(360, 5, 'exit-button', this.closeScreen, this, 1, 0, 2, 0);
  this.addChild(exitButton);

PointEditScreen.prototype.closeScreen = function() {
  this.destroy();
};
```

I am having a problem with `exitButton`. Its spritesheet has 3 frames and they all work in the states they are set to be used. Now, this code works - my "window" closes when I press the `exitButton`. However, if I set all four frames for `exitButton` like I have done in the above code, I get the following error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of null"
```

If I remove the last two frames (downFrame and upFrame) from the button creation, i.e. change it to the following, the error doesn't happen:

```
var exitButton = game.add.button(360, 5, 'exit-button', this.closeScreen, this, 1, 0);
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get rid of the error without removing those two frame declarations from the button creation?

Comment: Found someone with the same issue: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/9887-destroying-buttons-best-practices/

Could be a bug in Phaser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was a bug in Phaser and it is now working correctly in the newer version 2.3.0.